# Can I link a Create view for a model in a Details view for a different model using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I’m designing an ASP.NET MVC web app and am wondering how to structure the code needed for what I’d like it to do. It’s a scheduling app where you create a Show and then add a Band to the Show including the Band's start time and end time. To start simple, I'm only using 2 models and they are shown below (excluding attributes). I plan to scaffold a ShowsController with CRUD views but what I’d like to be able to do is create a new Show, see that Show displayed on the Index page of Shows and then when I click Details for the Show I created, I’d like to see all the details for that Show **and a link to add a Band to the Show.** Can I scaffold a BandsController with CRUD views and display a link to the Create view on the Details page of a Show that’s been created? Will I need to write a method for this in the ShowsController since I'd like to link the BandsController's Create view inside the ShowsController's Details view?

I’d be stoked if someone could give me some direction as to how to structure the code needed for this.

```
public class Show
{
public int ShowID { get; set; }

public DateTime Date { get; set; }

public string TourName { get; set }

public string Venue { get; set; }

public ICollection<Band> Bands { get; set; }
}

public class Band
{
public int BandID { get; set; }

public string BandName { get; set; }

public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

public Show Show { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Visual Studio does provide some tooling to scaffold views.  check this article. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29828936/how-to-scaffold-a-view-model-in-mvc-5

Comment: It looks like an Anchor Tag Helper was what I was looking for but I might end up incorporating a ViewModel too. Thanks!